# This code generates a segfault. Where have I gone wrong?

Tags: c++, strtok

The goal of this code is to quickly read some data into memory from fields in a tab delimited file and sort them.  I have found that when I run this code, I get a segmentation fault.  I assume it's something to do with my limited knowledge of strtok.  I know it would be easier to use some c++ functions for tokenizing strings, however, I would like to have this code run as fast as possible.  It seems like most c++ code would have me unnecessarily allocating space for new objects.  Ideally, the code will be run on files containing 100's of millions of lines. So, it needs to be fast.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;

    class Node
    {
      public:
      string name;
      int position1;
      int position2;
      string desc;
      float value;

      bool operator<(const Node& T) const;
    };

    bool Node::operator<(const Node &T) const
    {
      int result;
      result = name.compare(T.name);
      if (result !=0) return(result);

      if (position1 != T.position1) return(position1 < T.position1);

      if (position2 != T.position2) return(position2 < T.position2);

      return(false);

    }

    class NodeList
    {
      public:
      vector<Node> nodes;
    };


    int main(void)
    {
      string filename = "table.txt";
      FILE* infile = fopen(filename.c_str(), "r");

      int buflen = 1000;
      char buffer[buflen];

      NodeList K;
      Node T;


      while(fgets(buffer,buflen,infile) != NULL)
      {
         cout<< buffer << endl;

         T.name      = string(strtok(buffer, "\t\n"));
         T.position1 = atoi  (strtok(NULL  , "\t\n"));
         T.position2 = atoi  (strtok(NULL  , "\t\n"));
         T.desc      = string(strtok(NULL  , "\t\n"));
         T.value = atof  (strtok(NULL  , "\t\n"));

         K.nodes.push_back(T);
      }

      sort(K.nodes.begin(),K.nodes.end());

      return(0);

}
```

EDIT: The segfault occurs in the sort command. Without the sort command the code runs normally. Edited to take comments into account. Here is the output from the debugger:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0xffffffffffffffe8 0x00007fff83a078bb in std::string::compare ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff83a078bb in std::string::compare ()
#1  0x0000000100001333 in Node::operator< (this=0x7fff5fbfeef0, T=@0x1001fffe0) at test.cpp:27
#2  0x000000010000274e in std::__unguarded_linear_insert<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node*, std::vector<Node, std::allocator<Node> > >, Node> (__last={_M_current = 0x100200000}, __val=@0x7fff5fbfeef0) at stl_algo.h:2309
#3  0x0000000100003f28 in std::__unguarded_insertion_sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node*, std::vector<Node, std::allocator<Node> > > > (__first={_M_current = 0x100200200}, __last={_M_current = 0x1002581e0}) at stl_algo.h:2406
#4  0x000000010000437b in std::__final_insertion_sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node*, std::vector<Node, std::allocator<Node> > > > (__first={_M_current = 0x100200000}, __last={_M_current = 0x1002581e0}) at stl_algo.h:2439
#5  0x0000000100004422 in std::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node*, std::vector<Node, std::allocator<Node> > > > (__first={_M_current = 0x100200000}, __last={_M_current = 0x1002581e0}) at stl_algo.h:2831
#6  0x00000001000019e8 in main () at test.cpp:76
```

If I go up one level and look at the values, I get this:

```
(gdb) print T
$1 = (const Node &) @0x1001fffe0: {
  name = {
    _M_dataplus = {
      <std::allocator<char>> = {
        <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
      members of std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider:
      _M_p = 0x0
    }
  },
  position1 = 0,
  position2 = 0,
  desc = {
    _M_dataplus = {
      <std::allocator<char>> = {
        <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
      members of std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider:
      _M_p = 0x0
    }
  },
  value = 0
}
```

The values for this.name etc look like they come from the file, but whatever it is being compared to has values that are all 0's or NULL.

Comment: Get it right first; then measure whether it is fast enough.  Premature optimization is the root of much computing evil (and no, that isn't original to me).

Comment: -1 for poor research effort - please use a debugger.

Comment: How would you guarantee that each line you read would contain enough tabs? If it doesn't the first token would be split at \n i.e. newline and latter calls to strtok would return null. If you are certain each field of yours is separated by a tab, then don't use \n as an alternate except for the last call. Better yet, i believe you should use space as a separator

Comment: Also at least limit the scope of your segfault. For e.g. comment out the sort call and first only ensure if your seg fault is with in the tokenizer code. Debugger should have easily gotten you that.

Comment: You assign two different values to `T.position2`, one an `int` and the other a `double`.  It won't cause a crash, but it is unlikely to be correct. Ditto with `T.name` (two assignments, but both are strings, this time).

Comment: I did use a debugger actually. gdb. I was having trouble interpreting the STL related names. I know that it's the sort command that causes the segfault, although I'm assuming I must have corrupted something earlier.

Comment: As a matter of "correctness," consider using proper C++: `fstream`s, namely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling with `g++ -Wall -g`, I see that you need to include `string.h` to get `strtok`, and your `operator<` needs to return something if none of the earlier `if` statements were true. After that...

1. You aren't checking the return value of `fopen`, so the first segfault I found was when I hadn't created a `table.txt` to test with.
2. You aren't checking the return value of `strtok` either, so if no matching column exists, then you can pass `NULL` to `atoi`, and get a segfault there.

You need to use `gdb`'s `bt` command when your program crashes to find out what line triggered the crash.

Comment: I made the modifications you suggested.  There is still a segfault. It happens in the sort function.  (My less than operator always returrns something now.)

Comment: Look at the backtrace you got: either `this.name` or `T.name` is invalid, and is causing the call to `name.compare(T.name)` to crash.

Comment: @Jamey Sharp: Where would that come from? When I run through all the nodes in the vector, I only see the values from the file.

Comment: Hmmm. For that question, I have no answer.

Comment: @HenryB.: It's not enough just ensuring that operator< always returns something - it must return a consistent ordering for the elements. Right now, you're returning `true` whenever compare indicates the `name` strings are different, regardless of whether the difference is a less-than or greater-than relationship. That's totally wrong. Please study a few example implementations of `operator<`.

Comment: @TonyD: Yeah. You were right. I needed to write: if (name.compare(T.name)) return(name < T.name);  No segmentation fault after that alteration.  I think I just had a bit of a senior moment in terms of how compare works.